# clang 64 bit compiler backslashes single quotes inside strings, 32 bit doesn't

Tags: c++, sqlite, builder, clang++

I'm using Embarcadero c++ builder 10.2 Tokyo. I recently tried to upgrade my app from 32 bit to 64 bit. It works fine with the clang 32 bit compiler but when I tried upgrading to 64 bit I was swamped with errors relating to inline functions (body in .h file) supposedly being re-declared in any unit that includes the .h file. Having resolved that the long way I then found that the 64 bit compiler was backslashing single quotes in strings.

```
UnicodeString S="''";
in win32 S returns "''"
in win64 S returns "\'\'".
```

It's causing me havoc as I send a lot of strings to sqlite. I can't find anything in Project | Options that would let me turn this off and I'm not even sure how to best resolve it if the only solution is to doctor every string passed to sqlite. Anyone help?

Edit: My apologies. The backslashes appear in the IDE mouse over, watches, evaluate/modify etc. when the platform's win64 (they don't if it's win32). The blank returns I encountered in sqlite were down to something totally unrelated and nothing to do with phantom backslashes being passed to sqlite.

Comment: Can you show a program that reproduces the issue

Comment: It's likely that the strings are just shown differently. Are there two or four bytes before the zero terminator?

Comment: _the 64 bit compiler was backslashing single quotes in strings_ that does mean what? You know the difference between an IDE and a compiler?